# How to make Base class property generic in swift so can use with multiple model type?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocol-oriented

I want the property "cellViewModel" as generic so I can reuse BaseCustomCell with a different types of models.
Ex.

```
 struct CELLVIEWMODEL {
   var name: String
   var address: String
 }
 class BaseCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
       var cellViewModel: CELLVIEWMODEL  //should support different model types CELLVIEWMODEL1,CELLVIEWMODEL2
       {
        didSet() {
          setValuesInSubClasses
        }
      }
      func setValuesInSubClasses() {
       //subclass will implement
      }
 }

 class subCell: BaseCustomCell {
     override func setValuesInSubClasses() {
       //set value from cellViewModel
      }
 }
```

//This is how i am setting from cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: viewModel.getCellId(), for: indexPath) as! BaseCustomCell
        cell.cellViewModel = viewModel.getCellModelAtIndexPath(indexPath) //this will set values for subclasses
        return cell
    }
```

Now, I am creating new BaseCustomCell each time for different types of cellViewModel. Could you help with any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your goals.

You can make the actual `BaseCustomCell` glass generic, but be aware if you use Storyboards, this isn't a solution, since you'd need to hardcode the generic type into the storyboard.

The other solution that works with storyboards too is to declare your viewmodel as a protocol, then you can replace it with any concrete implementation of the protocol.

```
protocol CellViewModel {
    var name: String { get }
    var address: String { get }
}

class BaseCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var cellViewModel: CellViewModel {
        didSet() {
            setValuesInSubClasses
        }
    }
    
    func setValuesInSubClasses() {
       //subclass will implement
    }
}

class SubCell: BaseCustomCell {
     override func setValuesInSubClasses() {
       //set value from cellViewModel
      }
 }
```

And then your `viewModel.getCellModelAtIndexPath` should have a return type of `CellViewModel`, so it can return any type that conforms to the protocol.

So you simply need to declare your concrete cell view models like `class FirstCellViewModel: CellViewModel { ... }`, etc. and you can return them from `getCellModelAtIndexPath`

Comment: I am not using storyboard.  It looks good to me can you add some more explanation please.

Comment: @AvijitNagare not sure what more can I explain without going into a more specific problem. As I've said, just declare the type of `cellViewModel` as the protocol, make your `viewModel.getCellModelAtIndexPath` have the return type of the protocol, then inside the implementation of `getCellModelAtIndexPath`, you can return the concrete view model types depending on whatever criteria you have.

Comment: Was not able to set values for CellViewModel protocol type in subclass as i declared CellViewModel(Base Protocol) with not properties. but i subclass has properties and need to update cellViewModel(Whose properties not matching in  base cellViewModel). any solution to this.

Comment: @AvijitNagare just cast the `cellViewModel` to the concrete type using `cellViewModel as? YourType`